# Using regex on a on-screen keyboard

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Ok i'm really getting stuck here guys :/. I've got a (custom!) onscreen keyboard for which I wanna use regular expressions.

I Successfully created a regex to only allow `0-9` and a `comma` for a regular keyboard.

Of course this isn't working for my on-screen keyboard.

I have a code snippet that works...

BUT I also have a space button, a backspace button, and 2 buttons to move the caret around.

When I use the below regex code and click the space, backspace or the caret buttons I get this error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
    // the regex code   
    private Control keyb = null;
    private void EditProdPriceEx_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string AllowedChars = "[^0-9,]";
        if (Regex.IsMatch(EditProdPriceEx.Text, AllowedChars))
        {
            keyb = (Control)sender;
        }
    }
```

Space button:

```
    private void KnopSpatie_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tb = keyb as TextBox;
        int selStart = tb.SelectionStart; // here is where i get the error
        string before = tb.Text.Substring(0, selStart);
        string after = tb.Text.Substring(before.Length);
        tb.Text = string.Concat(before, " ", after);
        tb.SelectionStart = before.Length + 1;
    }
```

Backspace Button:

```
    private void KnopWissen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tb = keyb as TextBox;
        int cursorPosition = tb.SelectionStart; // here is where i get the error
        if (cursorPosition > 0)
        {
            tb.Text = tb.Text.Substring(0, cursorPosition -1) + tb.Text.Substring(cursorPosition);
            tb.SelectionStart = cursorPosition - 1;
        }
    }
```

Move caret left button:

```
    private void KnopLinks_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tb = keyb as TextBox;
        if (tb.SelectionStart > 0) // here is where i get the error
        {
            int selStart = tb.SelectionStart;
            string before = tb.Text.Substring(0, selStart);
            string after = tb.Text.Substring(before.Length);
            tb.SelectionStart = before.Length - 1;
        }
    }
```

Move caret right button:

```
    private void KnopRechts_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tb = keyb as TextBox;

        if (tb.SelectionStart >= 0) // here is where i get the error
        {
            int selStart = tb.SelectionStart;
            string before = tb.Text.Substring(0, selStart);
            string after = tb.Text.Substring(before.Length);
            tb.SelectionStart = before.Length + 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Wow...that has *nothing* to do with transactions...strange indeed!

Comment: @mortb Excuse me, i edited the error, i get these errors in dutch so i translated it wrong!

Comment: What error are you getting? You are not checking for `null`.

Comment: Yep, your `if`s will prevent the assignment of a value to tb. And then you get the exception later on in the other methods since it is null...

Answer (score 0):

I think you must try this. In the first Code.

```
// the regex code   
private Control keyb = null;
private void EditProdPriceEx_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string AllowedChars = "[^0-9,]";
    if (Regex.IsMatch(EditProdPriceEx.Text, AllowedChars))
    {
        keyb = (Control)sender;
    }
}
```

You made keyb null, and is not set by any key you mention (space and others), I think this produce the reference not set error. Can you check that?.

Comment: The `keyb = null;` is needed for my onscreen keyboard, which will send something like `A` or `B` etc to the textbox. So i think i'm looking in the wrong place.

Comment: Yes I know, but for the regex, if you press the space key for example, keep the ´keyb=null´ because you don't set it, and there for the reference is still null.

Comment: ahaaa! yes indeed, that makes perfect sense ! I'll have a look, thanks :)

Comment: i just took the easy way by using `KnopA , B, C etc... IsHitTestVisible = false;` a bit more work but also working